# AnyLogic not building and running the model

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am developing a simulation model of an automated distribution centre following the self-configuring approach explained in Benjamin Schumann's tutorial guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=casVdmKC-S0). Since the modelled environment is different, I am trying to use the same approach but with different agent types. Another difference is that I am using agent encapsulation. What I am experiencing is that as the model size increases (number of self-configured agents), the model takes a long time to start the simulation. When the model size increases even further, I get a chrome error page like the one below.

[image]

When I get the error, I am trying to create about 6100 agents, even though I am giving the simulation experiment a lot of RAM (16 GB).

To be more clear, the model structure and encapsulation can be seen in the following image:

[image]

All agent types are treated as populations to take advantage of the self-configuration feature suggested in the tutorial. Some populations have only one element, such as Asrs or Machine.
The agent populations with the largest number of objects are Storage Bins (about 3000) and Boxes (about 3000). The Storage Bin agent class consists of a few parameters, variables, collections, a few self-configuring functions, a few other functions, a few point nodes used to determine the positions of boxes within the agent, a few process blocks (enter, moveTo the node, wait, exit). The Box agent class only has parameters, variables and collections.

I managed the networks and layers within the encapsulation as suggested in the tutorial. For example, the point nodes of Storage Bin live in the network and level of the parent agent (Rack). Each additional point node of Rack lives in the network and layer of its parent agent (Aisle).

Graphically, the agents are very simple. The Storage Bin is a simple rectangle, the Box is a parallelepiped.

I create the agents and add them to the populations at model startup reading data from the database and use the data in the constructors of the agents. For speed, I use aggregated data. Taking as an example the creation of the Storage Bin population, since a rack structure is very repetitive, I have a row in the table for each rack, with data such as number of columns, levels and distances between columns and levels.

I use Anylogic University 8.7.12.

What do you think I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried profiling to see where memory is eaten? Are the agents simple `Agent` agents or more complex material-handling-library agents? The latter can be very demanding on performance and you should always use as few as possible...

Comment: I tried profiling but nothing strange happened. Among all the agent types, only Box is used as Material Handling within flowcharts. I also tried to eliminate the 3D window that I had in the Main agent, and now the model starts running. It takes time to load, but it not so laggy during simulation, so it could be fine. Do you think that there is some issue in the way that I render networks, levels, and presentation, as it seems that the problem is with visualization? Or could be the number of agents to be presented in 3D?

Comment: it could be many things, very hard to comment. Try it out. Also, start build models differently: add a tiny feature, test the hell out of it and only if everything is fine: repeat. This way, you never get surprised by some unexpected behavior or performance drop :)